# Error: Main method not found in class singleInheritance.A, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX

Tags: java

Please solve this problem.I've Spend 5 hours to solve this problem, but I could't.
I'm very thankful to you.Dear I was watching Java tutorial and in that particular video Instructor was writting his code in that case,That I've shown in my question,also there was no public class in his code.but he was writting code in notepad++, here is the screenshot[image: Instructor program],                and my program is here[image: my IDE screenshot]

```
package singleInheritance;

    public class A {
        void showA() {
            System.out.println(" a class method ");
        }
    }
    class B extends A{
        void showB() {
            System.out.println(" b class method ");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A ob1=new A();
            ob1.showA();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have wrong params of running the app. Check the config and look at the `Main class` in it. Check that it points to `singleInheritance.B` rather than `singleInheritance.A` In IDEA it looks like that:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If both `A` and `B` are in the same source file (probably A.java), the `main` method should be in class `A`, since that's the `public` class of that file.

If you want the `main` method to stay in class `B`, make `B` `public`, and put it in its own source file (`B.java`).

Comment: Why is it should be in `A`? (BTW, `the public method of that file` I suppose you meant `public class` ?) I just tried the code and it works fine. P.S. I don't argue with your answer, but I'd like to clarify it to myself, because maybe I don't know such thing.

Comment: I meant public class.Thanks

Comment: I'm very thankful to you.Dear I was watching Java tutorial and in that particular Instructor was writting his code in that case,That I've shown in my question, but he was writting code in notepad++.also there was no public class in his code.For explanation I want to send you screenshot.